# angular-cli --prod (AOT) polyfills module doesn't remove Angular 2 Compiler

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-aot

I ran the following command to get the stats.json

```
 node --max-old-space-size=4096 .\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng build --prod --stats-json
```

Then used [WebPack Bundle Analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) to inspect my project.

When running AOT (implicit with `--prod` flag) I see a compiler is bundled up in my **polyfills** output, which is not what I expected as I'm running Ahead of Time Compilation.

What should I change to stop this compiler being bundled up? Or where should I check?

[image: Webpack Bundle Analyzer output]

Answer (score 1):

OK I found the problem - duh.

Someone had added `import '@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd';` to the `pollyfills.ts` directly.

Comment: I would never guess :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should also add --aot flag.

```
ng build --prod --aot.
```

also you can run serve with aot

```
ng serve --prod --aot.
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the build by default use aot, the output is the same unless you specify `aot=false`. (using latest angular cli)

Comment: @Ploppy totally agree, but i guess they are not using the latest version :-)

Comment: Yea we're using the latest version. Just in case I also tried `--prod --aot` but still the same result

Comment: can you please recheck that in package.json is the latest verion?

Comment: and delete this line please --env=dev